# Jenkins: phpunit with namespaces in Yii-Framework

Tags: yii, jenkins, namespaces, continuous-integration, phpunit

I'm new to jenkins. I try to use the ci like on this [website](http://jenkins-php.org/). If I build my project I Get the following consol output error

```
phpunit:
 [exec] PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.
 [exec] 
 [exec] Cannot open file "/var/www/repo/project/protected/tests/bootstrap.php".
 [exec] 

BUILD FAILED
 /var/www/repo/build.xml:117: exec returned: 1
```

My build.xml

```
<target name="phpunit" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
  <exec executable="phpunit" failonerror="true">
     <arg line="--log-junit ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.xml /var/www/repo/project/protected/" />
 </exec>
 </target>
```

My Project structure is like this:

```
-repo
  -project
    -protected
      -components
      -config
      - ....
      - tests
         - unit
         - bootstrap.php
         - ReflectionTest.php
  -build
    -....
  -build.xml
  -phpunit.xml.dist
```

I'm using the Yii-Framework with namespaces. If I execute the phpunit command from the tests directory it works quite fine. But if I execute it somewhere else I get an error like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'application\tests\ReflectionTest' not found in /var/www/repo/project/protected/tests/unit/account/manager/ManagerTest.php on line 13
```

Here my test:

```
<?php

namespace application\tests\unit\account\manager;

use application\modules\account\manager\Manager;
use application\models;
use Yii;
use application\tests\ReflectionTest;

/**
 * This class test the protected and public methods of SignupManager
 */
class ManagerTest extends ReflectionTest {
```

And here my phpunit.xml.dist

```
<phpunit bootstrap="project/protected/tests/bootstrap.php"
        colors="false"
        convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
        convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
        convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
        stopOnFailure="false">

    <selenium>
        <browser name="Internet Explorer" browser="*iexplore" />
        <browser name="Firefox" browser="*firefox" />
    </selenium>

    <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>project/protected/tests/*</directory>
    </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

</phpunit>
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

I refer to my bootstrap file with the relative path from the location of the phpunit.xml file. Like this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
    colors="false"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    stopOnFailure="false">
```

Comment: it is the relativ path. The absolut path would be like this    /var/www/repo/project/protected/tests/bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample project for Yii on github. There you can see how the settings should be for phpunit to work correctly. Check out https://github.com/perlmonkey/yii-sample-project

Also, you must take care that all relevant PHPUnit modules are available for testing. That's why I created an automated script to take care of configuring Jenkins for me: https://github.com/perlmonkey/php-ci